# How to make and object find its own index in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple array of objects with a `id` property and I need the ids to be equal to their index. I tried this

```
var arr = [

  {
    id: arr.indexOf(this),
    length: this.length
  },
   {
    id: arr.indexOf(this),
    length: this.length
  },
   {
    id: arr.indexOf(this),
    length: this.length
  }

]
```

But that doesn't work. Do I have to use a function outside the array to do this? None of the built in methods would help?

Comment: You'd have to use `.findIndex()` outside of the initializer to do it "automatically", or you could just put `0`, `1`, and `2` in the object literals because it's all static code anyway.

Comment: It might be simplest to set up the array without the ids and then iterate over the array afterwards and fill them in.

Comment: The items in any array already have an index, why store it the second time? Does the order change and you need to retain original index?

Comment: The length is also already available. Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: Just a side note: if someway, somehow, somewhere, something prepends an element to the array, all the `id` keys will suddenly become invalid. It doesn't really seem to be a great design choice, doesn't it?..

Answer (score 2):

```js
// If this.length =3
var arr = [
  {length: 3},
  {length: 3},
  {length: 3}
]

arr.forEach((item, index)=> item.id =index)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: If the .length is supposed to be the array length then you can even fill that in in the foreach too.

Comment: @Rup is correct - the `.forEach` callback will take a third argument, which is the array itself.

Comment: @Rup in that case the array should have other property apart from length and id ,otherwise length will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you push to the array you can get the current array length and set it as id:

```
var array = []; 
array.push({id: array.length});
```

Also you can use a loop:

```
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < howeveryouwant; i++){
     array[i] = {id: i};
}
```

And if the initialization is static you could just set the ids:

```
 var arr = [

 {
    id:0,
    length: this.length 
 },
 {
    id: 1,
    length: this.length //this will be 0
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    length: this.length //this also will be 0
 }
```

];

Comment: For static initialisation, you can still use dynamic IDs - `var i = 0; arr = [ {id: i++}, {id: i++} ]`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `map` which takes the index and array as 2nd and 3rd parameter respectively:

```
const arr = [{title: 'A'}, {title: 'B'}, {title: 'C'}].map( (el, i, a) => ({id: i, ...el, length: a.length}));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following answer tries to address how you can use a class to create above structure and not have to loop to mutate length.

#### Idea:

- Create a function(`MyList`) which has an array that holds the objects.
- Create another function(`MyTempObject`) which only holds values that are specific to object.
- Move any common property, like `length` to prototype.
- In `MyList`, make the array as private and create a public property that returns a copy of this array. This will ensure that value is not mutable and can only be mutated using exposed APIs.

```js
function MyList () {
  var values = [];
  function MyListItem(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  Object.defineProperty(MyListItem.prototype, 'length', {
    get: function() { return values.length; }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'value', {
    get: function() { return values.slice(); }
  });
  
  this.add = function(id) {
    values.push(new MyListItem(id));
  }
}

var myList = new MyList();
myList.add(1);

console.log(myList.value)
console.log(myList.value[0].length)

myList.add(2);

console.log(myList.value)
console.log(myList.value[0].length)

myList.add(3);

console.log(myList.value)
console.log(myList.value[0].length)
```

---

One reason, you might wish to use this approach is in a scenario where you *add/delete* entry in this array. You will have to loop again and again to update the length in every object.

Comment: **Note:** I understand, this is not a direct answer and might be an overkill, but if OP/readers have option to create such structure instead of having an object literal, it would help. If you differ from my idea, please share your views in comment along with your vote.

Comment: @downvoter, please comment. A vote without comment will not help anyone